# Get old theme name when using switch_theme hook

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I would like to get the name of the theme from which I am switching and use it to add a custom option. Here is an example:

```
function new_options_func() {
    $theme = wp_get_theme();
    $theme_name = $theme->stylesheet;

    update_option( 'new_options_' . $theme_name, $something ); 
}
add_action( 'switch_theme', 'new_options_func' );
```

When I do it like this $theme_name is the theme to which I am switching, I would like it to be the name from which I am switch (old theme).

I need this to happen on switch_theme, not  after_switch_theme.

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you can get the name using get_option('theme_switched')